# Как моментально сменить обои?

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу сменить обои, но никак не могу найти действенный способ.
Нашёл вот такой способ, но получается только чёрный экран. Путь к файлу верен и расширение тоже.

```
SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID)"C:\\pic.bmp", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE )
```

Answer (score 0):

Я когда-то делал так:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,
                     (void*)filename,SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

Работало :), правда, только с BMP.

Comment: char filepath[]="C:\\pic.bmp"; 

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,(void*)filepath,SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

Абсолютно не работает.

Comment: Ну, могу разве что действующую программу приложить :) Что возвращает, что дает `GetLastError`?

Comment: GetLastError возвращает 998.
Приложите, может поможет)

Comment: Интересно - это `ERROR_NOACCESS`... А если файл убрать из корня `C:` и переложить в другое место - чтоб гарантированно проблем с правами доступа избежать?... у меня файл лежал в TMP-каталоге.

Comment: Если поместить в tmp-каталог, тогда мы вновь не наблюдаем реакции.
Но я заметил такую интересную вещь, если мы ошибаемся в пути к файлу или его имени то тогда видим чёрный экран вместо обоев которые были.
Не могли ли бы вы дать свой ВКонтакте или что-нибудь в этом роде? Думаю так будет удобней, но решать вам.